# How to click a webpage button using AutoHotKey

Tags: browser, autohotkey

I'm doing a script automation with navigating this a using AutoHotKey. I don't have that much knowledge on AHK. Is there a way to click the "Search by Parcel Number" button shown in the screenshot below using AHK? I noticed the Class changes with Active when the link is clicked.

My script so far:

```
        SendRaw Search by Parcel Number
        Sleep KeySleepSlow
        Send {esc}
        Sleep KeySleepSlow
        Send {enter}
```

[image]

[image]

Here is the website https://www.indy.gov/workflow/property-taxes

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways for AHK to interact with a webpage. A quick and dirty way would be to simply have AHK tell the browser to do it.

The Javascript can be used in the address bar to interact with a page, but there are a few tricks to it. The comments in the script below should explain it all:

```
+space:: ; Triggered with Shift+Space
    GoSub mySub1
Return
 
mySub1:
    ;The original clipboard contents is first saved in a variable so that it is not lost when the script is run.
    originialClipboard := Clipboard
    
    ;The clipboard is used so that the text is quickly entered into the address bar, instead of having each character typed out.
    ;Javascript is used to simulate a click on the desired document element. The 'j' is omitted by design.
    Clipboard := "avascript:document.evaluate(""//a[text()='Search by parcel number']"", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();"

    ;CTRL+L puts the text cursor in the address bar. Then the letter "j" is typed, because Chrome does not allow the text "javascript:" to be pasted in. The rest of that string will be pasted in later.
    send ^lj ;  

    ;CTRL+V pastes the clipbard 
    send ^v
    sleep 1 ;Sleep for a short moment to allow the browser to catch up.
    send {enter} ;The Enter key is sent, executing the javascript, simulating a click on the button.
    
    ;The clipboard is restored to its original value
    clipboard := originialClipboard
    
Return
```